# Issue passing arguments to a LaTex file

Tags: pdftex, windows, optional-arguments

I am trying to use the suggested answer to passing arguments to a LaTeX document, posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1466610/1227860) as solution#Three.

I am passing the argument as follows in my Windows Command Prompt:

```
C:\Users\afp\projects>pdflatex "\def\InputFilename{sample}\input{myLaTeXDoc.tex}"
```

In case the argument is not provided, I would like to have a default file to process. However, the compiler still complains about `Undefined control sequence. \begin{filecontents*}{\FILENAME.csv}`. I am not able to neither

- pass the argument at the command prompt nor
- generate a default csv file.

Could someone please help me with that?

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=0mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{readarray}
\readarraysepchar{,}

\usepackage{filecontents}

% If the argument is provided at the Windows command prompt, define \FILENAME as the input argument 
% otherwise define \FILENAME as a default comma-separated file to process.
\ifdefined\InputFilename
    \def\FILENAME{\InputFilename} 
\else
    \begin{filecontents*}{\FILENAME.csv}
        1,2,3
        4,5,6
        7,8,9
        10,11,12
    \end{filecontents*}
\fi

\begin{document}
    \wlog{filename is \FILENAME.csv}
    \readdef{\FILENAME.csv}\namedata
    \readarray\namedata\mydata[-,\ncols]
    \wlog{\FILENAME.csv has \nrows rows and \ncols columns.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you have not defined `\FILENAME` anywhere.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle wouldn't `\ifdefined\InputFilename
    \def\FILENAME{\InputFilename} 
\else
    \begin{filecontents*}{\FILENAME.csv}
        1,2,3
        4,5,6
        7,8,9
        10,11,12
    \end{filecontents*}
\fi` define `\FILENAME`?

Comment: not in the `\else` case no, what name do you want to write from filecontents?

Comment: Please see my answer. Why the data isn't displayed? Is there a similar thread, but with CSV data printed in a table in the output PDF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not define `\FILENAME` in the case that `filecontents*` is used, presumably you want something like this that defines it to be `\jobname`

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=0mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{readarray}
\readarraysepchar{,}

\usepackage{filecontents}

% If the argument is provided at the Windows command prompt use it 
% otherwise create a default comma-separated file to process.
\ifdefined\InputFilename
    \def\FILENAME{\InputFilename} 
\else
    \def\FILENAME{\jobname} 
    \begin{filecontents*}{\FILENAME.csv}
        1,2,3
        4,5,6
        7,8,9
        10,11,12
    \end{filecontents*}
\fi

\begin{document}
    \wlog{filename is \FILENAME.csv}
    \readdef{\FILENAME.csv}\namedata
    \readarray\namedata\mydata[-,\ncols]
    \wlog{\FILENAME.csv has \nrows rows and \ncols columns.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. it runs with no issue with the default file. However, I am still having issue running it with arguments at the command prompt. No matter what I input the log file always has `myLaTeXDoc.csv has 4rows and 3columns.` Seems like `\ifdefined\InputFilename` is never `true` although I am using `pdflatex "\def\InputFilename{sample}\input{myLaTeXDoc.tex}"`.

Comment: @AFP I am not sure, on the windows command line, do you need the quotes? I don't have a windows tex to test.  you can add `\show\InputFilename` to the start of your document and it will stop as if for an error and show the current meaning of `\InputFilename` so you can see if it is being defined. presumably you have a `sample.csv` if you are passing in `sample` ?

Comment: The compiler won't like it without the quote as `pdflatex \def\InputFilename{sample}\input{myLaTeXDoc.tex}`. and yes, the file `sample.csv` exists in the same directory.

Comment: @AFP hmm then I can't see why it doesn't work, can you show the log with and without `\def\InputFilename{sample}` ? I get `filename is sample.csv
sample.csv has 2rows and 4columns.`

Comment: Seems like the filename is passed and in the log, I can see the line `filename is sample.csv`. I also noticed an error as `! Undefined control sequence.
<write> \FILENAME .csv has \nrows 
                                  rows and \ncols columns.`

Comment: I got an undefined command error for `\nrows` if there was no sample.csv @AFP

Answer (score 1):

The answer didn't work for me, I had to change something:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=0mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{readarray}
\readarraysepchar{,}


% If the argument is provided at the Windows command prompt, define \FILENAME as the input argument
% otherwise define \FILENAME as a default comma-separated file to process.
\ifdefined\InputFilename
    \def\FILENAME{\InputFilename}
\else
    \def\FILENAME{\jobname.csv}
    \begin{filecontents*}{\FILENAME}
        1,2,3
        4,5,6
        7,8,9
        10,11,12
    \end{filecontents*}
\fi

\begin{document}
    Filename is \FILENAME
    \readdef{\FILENAME}\namedata
    \readarray\namedata\mydata[-,\ncols]
    \FILENAME has \nrows rows and \ncols columns.
\end{document}
```

I got the PDF created:

> Filename is Tabela.csv Tabela.csvhas 301rows and 4columns.

Comment: Please don't use the answer box to post questions, leave a comment or post a new question referencing this.